# Change char in a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

What regular expression should I use with the 'replace()' function in JavaScript to change every occurrence of char '_' in 0, but stop working as long as finding the char '.'?

Example:

> _____323.____  ---> 00323._
>
> ____032.0____  --> 0032.0_

Are there ways more efficient than to use 'replace()'?

I am working with numbers. In particular, they can be both integer that float, so my string could never have two dots like in __32.12.32 or __31.34.45. At maximum just one dot.

What can I add in this:

```
/_(?=[\d_.])/g
```

to also find '_' followed by nothing?

Example: 0__ or 2323.43_

This does not work:

```
/_(?=[\d_.$])/g
```

Comment: You can use `replace()` along with reg-ex, what is your choice?

Comment: @dystroy sorry, i dropped my comment before seeing yours and your answer.

Comment: Is there always a period?

Comment: @JasonMcCreary I understand *"they can be both integer that float [...] At maximum just one dot"* as a NO.

Comment: Given that \_032.0\_ is possible, why isn't \_032.\_0 possible ?

Comment: @sin It's a little long to explain, however _032._0 is not possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use

```
str = str.replace(/[^.]*/,function(a){ return a.replace(/_/g,'0') })
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)

Comment: Can you explain how replace works when 2nd parameter is a function?

Comment: @Umur: Look it up here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: @Jongware I know how that works actually, I wanted it to make it a better answer since it is a smart one.

Comment: @UmurKontacı I added the reference.

Comment: **very nice usage** of the global flag ( when is not present) +1

Answer (score 1):

Without replace/regex:

```
var foo = function (str) {
  var result = "", char, i, l;
  for (i = 0, l = str.length; i < l; i++) {
    char = str[i];
    if (char == '.') {
      break;
    } else if (char == '_') {
      result += '0';
    } else {
      result += str[i];
    }
    char = str[i];
  }
  return result + str.slice(i);
}
```

With regex: dystroy

Benchmark for the various answers in this post:
http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-no-regex-replace

Comment: Non-regex needn't be that large an answer: `var str = "__323.__345._";
var newstr = str.substr(0,str.indexOf('.')).replace(/_/g,'0')+str.substr(str.indexOf('.'));`

Comment: @SmokeyPHP There's a regex in your comment.

Comment: @dystroy Funny.. yes of course - I mean of course a solution that takes most of the effort away from the regex (my tests prove up to 2x performance increase)

Comment: @Aegis That's fab, thanks for getting involved and all, but I meant against the regex solution provided by dystroy.

Comment: @SmokeyPHP I know, I'll add that to the test. My point is just that if you want performance then avoiding regex is a good idea, even just one :p

Comment: @Aegis Yea, I know - the performance wasn't even a major point of it, just a less regex dominated snippet that wasn't as long

Comment: Just a note : be careful with those jsperf. As the code isn't optimized, they don't show how the function really perform (but I still expect Aegis's code to be faster than mine on short strings). See http://jsperf.com/substrorregex/3

Comment: @dystroy thanks for the notice; I actually read elsewhere that the slow part in regex is their creation, not the match. It might be part of the why, in your test, the difference is much thinner.

Comment: Yes, simple regular expressions (no back reference) were explicitly designed to be fast from the start.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have some other obscure condition -

find:

```
 _(?=[\d_.])
```

replace:

```
 0
```

Or "To find also _ followed by nothing, example: 0__ or 2323.43_"

```
_(?=[\d_.]|$)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use lookahead assertion in regex...

```
"__3_23._45_4".replace(/_(?![^.]*$)/g,'0')
```

Result: `003023._45_4`

Explanation:

```
/          # start regex
_          # match `_`
(?!        # negative lookahead assertion
[^.]*$     # zero or more (`*`) not dots (`[^.]`) followed by the end of the string
)          # end negative lookahead assertion
/g         # end regex with global flag set
```

Comment: Note: fails on `__323.__345._` (if that situation were to crop up)

Comment: As for me, it stops only before the last `.` character, ignoring all previous (replacing undescores).

Comment: That don't work even in Python: `re.sub(r'_(?![^.]*$)', "0", "__3_23._45_4._5")` result: `'003023.04504._5'`

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "___345_345.4w3__w45.234__34_";

var dot = false;
str.replace(/[._]/g, function(a){
  if(a=='.' || dot){
    dot = true;
    return a
  } else {
    return 0
  }
})
```

Comment: About your str : "At maximum just one dot".